# В Emmet перестала работать аббревиатура восклицательный знак ! знак

Tags: html5, visual-studio-code

Работаю в текстовом редакторе VS Code, где уже установлен Emmet. Все аббревиатуры работают, перестала работать аббревиатура восклицательный знак ! знак, при создании документа. Пожалуйста подскажите!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такая же проблема возникла сегодня.
Решилось так - в настройках нужно найти emmet trigger, поставить галку и перезапустить VS Code.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!